# copy element from one dgn to another dgn

Tags: microstation

Is there an equivalent command in microstation for the copyclip with basepoint from autocad to copy an element from one dgn to another dgn?

I tried attaching a reference and copying it that way, but then I can not detach that reference.

I get an error message about not being able to detach a model from a managed model.

Comment: Welcome to SO @TMOSER.  Can you post your code?  Can you also post the actual error message?

Comment: @ewitkows he wasn't doing programming. He was using Microstation GUI to attempt to merge a DGN file. So there was no code to show.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you considered using the [FF (FILEFENCE)](http://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/15080.can-the-fence-file-or-ff-commands-be-used-in-batch-process) command?

As you can see from the help topic it can be used in batch processing.

In short, you place a fence around the content to be saved to another file and then in the command window:

```
ff=<path_to_new_dgn>
```

Then, once you have your file, open the other DGN, and **attach** this new file as a **reference**.

Now go into the reference manager and right-click the attachment. Choose [Merge to Master](http://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/17011.how-to-merge-into-master)

Now the contents will be part of your DGN file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the element(s) you want to copy.
2. Set a tentative snap point on the basepoint about which you'd like to copy. To set a tentative point, the default key is middle mouse button. If that button is not assigned, see [this link](https://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/16851/tentative-snap-not-working).
3. Menu Bar > Edit > Copy
4. Open the drawing you'd like to copy into.
5. Menu Bar > Edit > Paste
6. Ensure your settings in the "Paste from Clipboard" dialog box are correct (angle, x scale, y scale).
7. Click where you'd like to paste.